# Get handle of device with non-admin user

Tags: c++, winapi, device, administrator

In my C++ DLL I use the `CreateFile` C++ function in order to get device handle. I have to use it with the `GENERIC_WRITE` parameter. 
On Vista and later in order to make it work I need admin privileges, but I want to run this DLL with other users too.

note: the administrator wants that the other user will do the task I'm doing in the DLL.

Does someone know another API to use or a workaround for this?

Comment: I think you'll have to run a service with admin privs to do the work and your users will have to ask the service to make whatever changes. Can you tell us exactly what you're doing, though? The resource you're trying to modify was probably marked admin-only for a reason.

Comment: this can be a workaround. but how can I change my dll to a service? there is a GUI using this dll, how can I use a service to call function from GUI application?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the functionality of the dll as a COM object you can use the [COM Elevation Moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The COM elevation moniker allows applications that are running under user account control (UAC) to activate COM classes with elevated privileges. For more information, see Focus on Least Privilege.
>
> [...]
>
> The elevation moniker is used to activate a COM class to accomplish a specific and limited function that requires elevated privileges, such as changing the system date and time.
>
> Elevation requires participation from both a COM class and its client. The COM class must be configured to support elevation by annotating its registry entry, as described in the Requirements section. The COM client must request elevation by using the elevation moniker.